# Comunicacion entre servidores SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia internautas! tengo una pequeña duda/problema, resulta que tengo una tabla en una bd de un sv #1 y necesito que cuando se inserte en esa tabla, actualice la misma tabla en una bd de un sv #2, ¿como puedo hacer esto?
muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas permisos de administracion , abres tu Sql server manegement studio
en tu raiz existe un folder llamado 'Servver Objects/ Linked Servers'

presionas boton derecho la conexion la realizas como cuando realizas una conexion normal a base de datos:

Estableces: Provider, Product name, Data source , Location, user, pass...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ultimo solo haces una prueba de conexion.

aqui esta mas detallado:
https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Las consultas las realizas mediante OPENDATASOURCE:

```
SELECT *  
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',  
    'Data Source=DEV_SQL;Integrated Security=SSPI')  
    .testdb.dbo.AddressBook
```

Answer (score 0):

Opción 1:
Si tienes permisos administrativos en ambos servidores puedes linkear el servidor.
Desde T-SQL con el código.
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = N'sv2',
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;
Tu procedimiento almacenado o T-SQL debe tener la instrucción para ambos servidores
insert into **sv1.db.propietario.tabla** (campos)values(valores)
insert into **sv2.db.propietario.tabla** (campos)values(valores)

Opción 2:
**Configuras Mirroring**
Click derecho en la base de datos, seleccionas la opción Mirroring y continuas el asistente.
[image: Ejemplo Mirroring]

Ten presente que para configurar mirroring necesitas como requisito:
 1. Tener la base de datos configurada en su recovery model : FULL
 2. Realizar el backup de la base de datos y restauras en el servidor objetivo con la opción del recovery en modo : RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY
 3. Realizar un backup del archivo de transacciones y restaurarlo de la misma forma que el paso 2

Una vez configures mirroring todo lo que hagas en la base de datos # 1, será replicada a la base de datos # 2